# Can cacti display some TEXT output from mib at my graph?

Tags: linux, monitoring, snmp, cacti, rrdtool

My switch can check if there is an SFP connector present in its ports and their respective link status.
I want to display this information in Cacti graphs for each interface of my switch.
The switch gives output in this format:

some_oid.1 = Description of port
some_oid.2 = Port Mac Addr
some_oid.3 = UP/DOWN (for Link)
some_oid.4 = YES/NO (for SFP connector)

I configured Cacti to get this information for all ports via a PHP script, but I don't know how to modify the graph template to display this information.

Screenshot of my desired result: [image: https://pp.vk.me/c622022/v622022509/27f5e/-cSLkjgV3rg.jpg]

Comment: I assume that screenshot is what you're looking for, not what you've got now?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the OID for the SFP status, but it's simple to add the others.

Duplicate your graph template that you use (I like having the total bandwidth)
[image: duplicate]
Add comment lines to your graph that include query for the items you want
[image: items]

Here is one item so you can see how I made them, they are all pretty much the same...
[image: item]

Change your graphs to use this template, or if you want it within the list of available templates when you create graphs for a device, then edit the Data Query to include this template...

*"Data Queries" >> "SNMP - Interface Statistics" >> Add the graph template, and duplicate its settings from the original graph.*

Here is my graphs;

[image: result]

Adding the SFP information would be simple if you know the OID. Edit the XML resource/snmp_queries/interface.xml to include the base OID for the SFP status.